# List view music list, of song

Tags: java, android, media-player

I added to the raw folder'm developing an application that plays music. 
By clicking the song is playing music to a ListView. but the music does not pass to the next song when finished. What should I do?

and I'm using translate sorry

```
public class LoadedActivity extends Activity {
MediaPlayer mp;
View View;
ListView listView;
Drawable Drawble;
ImageButton OynatButonu;         
ImageButton DurdurButonu;
ImageButton IleriButonu;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.loaded_layout);

    Field[] fields = R.raw.class.getFields();
    String[] mediaList = new String[fields.length];
    for (int count = 0; count < fields.length; count++)
        mediaList[count] = fields[count].getName();

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.music_list);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            LoadedActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            mediaList);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int position,
                long id) {
            if (View != null)
                ((TextView) View).setBackgroundDrawable(Drawble);
            Drawble = ((TextView) v).getBackground();

            String uri = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/raw/"
                    + ((TextView) v).getText();

            if (mp != null && mp.isPlaying())
                mp.stop();

            mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), Uri.parse(uri));
            mp.start();

            ((TextView) v).setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
            ((TextView) v).setTextColor(Color.RED);
            View = v;                         
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try add [OnCompletionListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener.html) to your media player like this:

```
mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            mp.setDataSource("your_next_song_url");
            mp.prepare();
            mp.start();

        }
    });
```

Comment: I could not. exactly where you need to add.

Comment: Add the completionListener to your current media player. Inside your click listener you can do this. Below the mp.start(), btw.

See this tuto > [link](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/03/android-building-audio-player-tutorial/)

Comment: I do not know english, to me this sounds too complicated course. 
eklermisin between my my code could you please? 
Thank you for helping me.

Comment: here is an example > [Gist code](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/907e490fe8b5414f1bd1)

I didn't test but maybe it can help you

Comment: I did, but it did not. 
the song is playing and stops. does not pass to the next song.

Comment: has failed. the picture below

Answer (score -1):

gives this error.
mp.setdatasource("/raw/");  Is it true?

[image]